# How to launch startup program on specific time

Tags: startup

Flux is nice application for those working on night time, it gives you warm color temperature on night time. I've been happily enjoying using it, [link](https://justgetflux.com/) for anyone interested.

Color temperature changes on Flux started on 6PM, but rather than letting Flux modify my computer display I'd prefer turn the lights on.

This behavior makes me have to close the Flux manually, which is inconvenience.

Is there any way to make Flux only:

- Launch between 8PM to 3AM
- Stop between 3AM to 8PM

Comment: This looks like ma feature request.

Comment: Can be done, but are you running the fluxgui indicator?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes, I'm using `fluxgui`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## First step : create the script

First let us create a script the will be run and would enable/disable flux depending on the time (I don't knot flux syntax, so adapt it for your need). You can note that here I suppose that you need to be root to run flux, but of course if you don't just run these steps as a classical user.

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/flux/
sudo gedit /opt/flux/toogleFlux.sh
```

and put in it something like this

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

h=$(date +%H)
start=20
stop=3
export DISPLAY=:0
if [ $h -ge $start ] || [ $h -lt $stop ] ; then
    # Start flux, give it any information you want, latitude...
    xflux -l 45
else
    # Stop flux
    killall xflux
fi
```

Then, make it executable :

```
sudo chmod +x /opt/flux/toogleFlux.sh
```

## Second step : run it when needed

Now, you need to run it when needed. To to so, you can use a `cron` that would run it at 8:05 PM and 3:05 AM. But if you do so, if you open your computer at 8:10PM, it would not run it. The first solution is to use `fcron`, but I don't think it's packaged on distributions, so I'll use a combinaison of `cron` and a file that runs when you open a session.

To run this script with cron, run the following command. If you need to run it as root, add `sudo` before :

```
crontab -e
```

and then type :

```
05 20 * * * /opt/flux/toogleFlux.sh
05 3 * * * /opt/flux/toogleFlux.sh
```

now, you need to be sure that the script will run when you open your session. Depending on your GUI, you can configure it in your system settings, or sometimes putting this line in `.profile` will be enough (the `xhost` command is usefull to let the root user connect to the graphical interface) :

```
xhost +local:
/opt/flux/toogleFlux.sh
```

Now, run it `toogleFlux.sh` to enable it for the current session :

```
xhost +local:
/opt/flux/toogleFlux.sh
```

and enjoy flux !

Comment: Most likely, just killing flux will leave the screen in colored mode. Also not quite sure if running from cron like this on the GUI won' t have issues. So the main question is: did you test?

Comment: The kill send a SIGTERM, not a SIGKILL so it is supposed to kill it smoothly, so that flux could revert it's configuration back. Moreover, since Liso says that when he stops flux manually it works, I don't see why here it would not work. Please try my solution, and if it does not work, explain what is see/expected, and we will look for another solution.

Comment: ...That's why I asked him if he is using the indicator (gui) which does take care of it. `killall flux` does nothing on my system, let alone from cron, but it' s not my job to find out that this happens, nor why. No offense, but testing your stuff is essential.

Comment: The original question was about lanching program on specific time, and I answered that. Moreover, I do not want to install useless stuff on my system, especially when flux won't work on it. However, I tried and when I run it I have a message saying "Going to background: 'kill 18938' to turn off.". So running killall xflux should work. (note the x of xflux)

Comment: While *Killing* xflux from crontab works (of course), but *running* xflux does not work like this (meaning: has no effect). The script will therefore fail.

Comment: ...in short, you need to set the `DISPLAY` variable when running GUI stuff from cron.

Comment: I added the ```DISPLAY``` export, and also some commands to run ```xhost``` to be sure that the user has the right to connect to GUI. Since I cannot test it on my system, I'd be glad to know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share an alternative software that you can/should check, [redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) *(with its indicator `redshift-gtk`)*, I prefer it over *flux* for some reasons, foss, its on main repos, auto adjust color temp based on location/sunset time, easy manual settins *(color temp, times...)* , etc.

From author's page:

[image: redshift example]

You can simply run `sudo apt install redshift-gtk` on your terminal, and then launch it from *Unity's dash*. Also the indicator *(a light bulb)* has itself an option to make it autostart.

[image: redshift indicator]

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE:** As @JacobVlijm explained in comments *(thanks for that)*, launching from cronjob seems to be not so simple as for non-GUI apps, so I changed my answer to simply show an alternative software solution.

Comment: I don't want to seem cranky, but the combination of suggesting stuff you didn't try (*"putting the command into a simple script and launch it from a cronjob"*, not working like this), and just thinking aloud, makes a bad answer.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Sorry for that, i thought it was better to point to tobiasBora's answer first as example _(better direct answer to OP question)_ and all I wanted was to show an alternative which I think also solves OP question but not in the manner he's asking for. Should I remove my answer?

Comment: @JacobVlijm answer updated, I would like to have your thought about this. Is now ok? I have no problems deleting a _bad_ answer and I'd like to contribute, but doing things well.

Comment: Thanks for editing @dgonzalez, but neither of the current answers will work. When running GUI stuff rom cron, you need to set the `DISPLAY` variable in any case, possibly also additional environment variables (when editing `gsettings` for example), since cron runs with a limited set of environment variables.  That's why I think answers should always be tested before posting. Be sure btw I haven't the slightest doubts in your intentions, and appreciate your effort(s).

Comment: Answer updated. @JacobVlijm thanks for what I learned about cronjobs while walking the way ;)

Comment: No way, thanks for pointing me into the right path while sharing your wisdom!